# Are subsets of two independent sets independent?

Tags: probability

If sets $A$ and $B$ are independent ($P(A \cap B)=P(A)P(B)$), and $a$ is subset of $A$ while $b$ is subset of $B$, then are $a$ and $b$ independent as well?

Answer (score 5):

No. For an even simpler argument: $P(\Omega)=1=P(\Omega)^2$ would imply events are always independent.

Comment: This is a good idea, but without further explanation (why aren't events "always independent"?), it falls short of what one might expect to post in answer to a two year old Question.

Comment: I believe there is already an example of non-independent events in the answers to this same question. I'm just exposing a neat degenerate case.

Answer (score 3):

No.  For example, suppose $A$ is the event that the first coin comes up "heads", and $B$ is the event that the second coin comes up "heads".

Then let $a$ be the event that they both come up "heads" and let $b$ be the event that the second coin comes up "heads" and the first does not.

Answer (score 2):

Space $=\{1,2,3,4\}$, $P(\text{point})=1/4$, $A=\{1,2\}$, $B=\{1,3\}$, $a=b=\{1\}$.
$$P(A\cap B)=P(\{1\})=\frac14=P(A)P(B)$$
$$P(a\cap b)=P(\{1\})=\frac14\ne \frac1{16}=P(a)P(b)$$

Answer (score 2):

No. $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$ **and** $B$ but in general $A\cap B$ and $A\cap B$ are not independent.

That should require $P(A\cap B)\in\{0,1\}$ and is not in general implied by independency of $A$ and $B$.